# IntelliJ: Best way to save before a significant modification

Tags: intellij-idea, save

What is the best way to save an IntelliJ project before you implement a change that may or may not work, and will be difficult to undo?

I come from a computer animation background in Maya, and one idea which I like a lot in Maya which I feel should transfer to programming is the ability to "plus save".  What I mean by this is that you can save your project as a sequence of files/folders rather than just a single file/folder so that if it comes to pass that your latest decisions have become more burdensome than expected, you can simply go back to an earlier version of the project and make different choices.

I ask this because I am working on a Java project with multiple classes which I want to modify to use generics.  It takes a long time to look at every function and determine whether it conforms or not.  If it doesn't work out the way I hope, I want to be able to revert to the old version without spending a great deal of time going back through everything again.

I suppose I could just manually copy the folder contents, but I was hoping there might be an often used technique I am unaware of.

Comment: By committing the code to your version control system. The IDE is irrelevant here. Google for "git".

Comment: Use the version control or build-in IntelliJ IDEA Local History.